# Converting Dates on java

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I have a `jCalendar` which method `jCalendar.getDate()` returns a date in the following form:
Mon Apr 06 11:10:00 PDT 2015
But I want it in the format yyyy-MM-dd to insert into a MySQL database 
I tried the following code but it throws a ParseException

```
Date fecha = jFecha.getDate(); //this returns Mon Apr 06 11:10:00 PDT 2015
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            fecha = format.parse(fecha.toString());
```

This code returns a `Unparseable date: "Mon Apr 06 11:10:00 PDT 2015"` error. I've tried setting the `dateFormatString` property of the `jCalendar` to yyyy-MM-dd but it still returns the same full date with seconds and everything.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Dont't use `toString()`. Directly use `fecha` as the parameter.

Comment: You are trying to parse a date from its string representation using the date format specified. No wonder it doesn't work! I think what you want is format the date into a string?

Comment: BTW a date does not have a format, you format a date to obtain a string, so your `fecha` object does not have any embedded format information, if that's what you're thinking.

Comment: And I'ts better to use `java.sql.Date` to save dates, and not `java.util.Date`, which I think it's your case, you will need get the date as `util.Date` or `String` and convert into a `sql.Date`

Comment: I haven't saved the date yet, but regardless of the format of my java Date using java.sql.Date will work? I also tried `fecha = format.parse(fecha);` but it marks an error of `Incompatible types: Date cannot be converted to String`

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a `Date` object does not have a format by itself. You cannot have "a `Date` object in the format yyyy-MM-dd" - there's no such thing as a `Date` object in a certain format.

How are you inserting the `Date` in the database - are you using JDBC? If yes, then use a `PreparedStatement` and pass a `java.sql.Date` object as the parameter. Like this:

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(
        "insert into mytable (name, date) values (?, ?)");

ps.setParameter(1, "somename");
ps.setParameter(2, new java.sql.Date(fecha.getTime()));

ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: I'll try that. I was unsure of passing a java Date to the method where I insert statements on the database, but in that method I do use `java.sql.Date`, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

> I want it in the format yyyy-MM-dd to insert into a MySQL database

**No need to generate or parse a String**. With a `Date` object in hand, convert to a `java.time.Instant`, apply a time zone `ZoneId` to generate a `ZonedDateTime`, and extract a `LocalDate`. Pass the `LocalDate` via JDBC 4.2 and later.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 
    … ,
    myJavaUtilDate.toInstant()
                  .atZone( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) )
                  .toLocalDate() ,
    LocalDate.class
)
```

## Details

> jCalendar.getDate() returns a date in the following form: Mon Apr 06 11:10:00 PDT 2015

The old `Date` & `Calendar` classes have many flaws. One of the flaws is the poor design decision to have the `Date::toString` method apply a time zone during the process of generating the string. This creates the illusion of an assigned time zone when actually the `Date` value is always in UTC.

Avoid the troublesome old date-time classes. They are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Convert that `Date` to an `Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = myUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

For a date-only value, you must decide on time zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in Paris France is a new day while in Montréal Québec is still “yesterday”. So you must specify the context of a zone to determine the intended date.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

For a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone, extract a `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

To exchange date-time values with a database, use date-time objects rather than mere strings. No need for you to generate or parse that problematic string.

If your JDBC driver complies with JDBC 4.2 and later, you can directly use the java.time types rather than the legacy java.sql types.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject ( 1 , ld ); // Automatic detection and conversion of data type.
```

…and…

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject ( "my_date_column_" , LocalDate.class );
```

For more discussion, see [*Insert & fetch java.time.LocalDate objects to/from an SQL database such as H2*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43039614/642706).

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score -1):

Do this instead:

```
Date fecha = jFecha.getDate(); //this returns Mon Apr 06 11:10:00 PDT 2015
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        fecha = format.format(fecha);
```

Actually you are supposed to use format instead of parse